# Pyspark Dataframe metadata

Tags: pyspark

Is there a way to get metadata about ALL the dataframes?  I'd be interested in something like a list of dataframes with information about each (memory distribution information, etc.)  I don't see anything in the docs that shows how to do this.

I'm think of this as a troubleshooting tool when I'm having memory issues.  If I'm working on a big script that creates, caches and unpersists lots of dataframes,  it would be really nice to be able to display a list of dataframes so that I could see if I've missed anything or my caching settings are wrong or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: to check DF's that are cached I think spark.catalog [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html) is the best option. For memory management other than just checking driver's webpage I have no idea..

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This looks like at least part of what I was looking for.